# transmission-daemon вызов скрипта после окончания загрузки

Tags: linux, ubuntu

### Предыстория

Установил Ubuntu-server на старенький комп и оставил его в подвале. Решил на нем настроить медисервер. Поставил для загрузок transmission-daemon для воспроизведения файлов gerbera.

### Проблема

При использовании оказалось, что телевизор Samsung не может принимать avi видео, а сделать так, чтобы все онлайн перекодировалось не выходит.

Так вот хочу сделать скрипт на bash, который будем перекодировать видео из avi в mkv, и по завершению перемещать файл.

Хотело бы узнать: в transmission есть параметр который запускает скрипт по завершению загрузки? Может ли эта команда передать аргументом имя загружаемого файла? Или чтобы gerbera на лету перекодировала файл.

Comment: Кажется, вы путаете видеоконтейнеры и видеокодеки. Для преобразования avi в mkv перекодирование не требуется, это может быть просто перепаковка в другой контейнер. И наоборот, есть возможность перекодировать avi в совершенно другой avi с другим кодеком, потому что avi это всего лишь контейнер. Так что рекомендую вам предварительно уточнить, что именно не поддерживает ваш телевизор - контейнер avi или видеокодек, которым закодировано видео в этом avi

Comment: @andreymal не вникал так сильно, но могу предположить что не потдерживается именно контейнер avi, так как пробывал около 10 разных видео

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> в transmission есть параметр который запускает скрипт по завершению загрузки?

см. образец конфигурационного файла (обычно `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`):

```
...
"script-torrent-done-enabled": false,
"script-torrent-done-filename": "",
...
```

первый из них включает/выключает запуск скрипта, во втором надо указать путь к скрипту (файл должен быть доступен на чтение и выполнение пользователю, от имени которого работает демон).

информация скрипту передаётся через переменные окружения:

- `$TR_APP_VERSION` — версия демона
- `$TR_TORRENT_ID` — идентификатор торрента (число, показывается, например, в выводе `transmission-remote -l`)
- `$TR_TORRENT_NAME` — имя торрента в том виде, как оно отображается в интерфейсе
- `$TR_TORRENT_DIR` — каталог, в котором находится торрент
- `$TR_TORRENT_HASH` — хэш торрента
- `$TR_TIME_LOCALTIME` — дата и время запуска скрипта.

Comment: А вот это именно то что мне и надо, огромного спасибо.  Просто я был на оф. сайте transmission и не нашёл там какой либо документации. Ещё раз огромное спасибо